# Raising custom error message in parsley.js

Tags: parsley.js

I am asking this question for the second time because I didn't manage to solve the issue the last time.

I have a complex rule according to which I should validate user input. For the purpose of simplicity, let's assume that the input value should be divisible by 5. 
Consider this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RT5aN/465/)

```
var elem = $('#name').parsley();
var error_name = 'custom_error';
elem.removeError(error_name);
elem.addError(error_name, {message:'Custom error msg'});
```

Why is the reason this code does not work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much better to not use `addError` and `removeError` and to instead use a custom validator. There are good examples in the doc.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you for this. You encouraged me to read further, and I learnt new things about parsley

Answer (score 0):

Here's reference http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#ui-for-field

Add the container to hold the message in the form

```
<p class="error-container"></p>
```

To Add the custom error

```
let specificField = $('#error-container').parsley();
window.ParsleyUI.addError(specificField, "myCustomError", "custom error text goes here ");
```

To remove the custom error

```
let specificField = $('#error-container').parsley();
window.ParsleyUI.removeError(specificField, "myCustomError");
$(".parsley-myCustomError").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: Could you please demonstrate it in JS fiddle ? I have tried your suggestion, bu nothing works (http://jsfiddle.net/ou7mwrk7/)